# how to calculate the mean value of an incomplete matrix with maxima?

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

maybe I miss the obvious, but how do I get the mean value of the following matrix ?

```
matrix( [      ,        ,           ],
        [7.5133,        ,   5.3     ],
        [4.93  , 5.7667 ,   2.9067  ] );
```

I tried mean, geometric_mean, ... and the other commands from the descriptive package, but they don't work with missing values.

regards,
Marcus

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand how you typed in that matrix. I get an error message when I copy that into Maxima, because of the commas which don't have actual elements between them.

Comment: Dear Robert,sorry for the late reply to your comment. Your are right, I typed the matrix with a1: matrix([NIL, NIL, NIL],[7.5, NIL, 5.3],...) and later I used matrixmap(lambda([u], if u = NIL then "" else u),a1); to get rid of the NIL's. I tried it that way around, because I thought NIL might be the root cause of the problems with mean() and I later never changed it back.  Regards, Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one have to implement it. For example

```
M: matrix(
  [ und  ,      und,   und],
  [7.5133,      und,   5.3],
  [4.93  ,  5.7667 ,   2.9067] ) $

ulength(x):=block([n: 0], matrixmap(lambda([e], if e#'und then n: n + 1), x), n) $
usum(x):=block([s: 0], matrixmap(lambda([e], if e#'und then s: s + e), x), s)    $
umean(x):=usum(x)/ulength(x) $
umean(M);
```

Comment: Dear slitvinov,

Comment: Dear slitvinov, thank you very much for your solution. It solved my problem just fine and all I had to add is a map call to replace the empty cells with 'und.

Comment: my reputation is too low to vote you up, sorry for that. regards, Marcus